# How do I colorize variables with Winston?

Tags: javascript, logging, colors, winston

I want to log variables with a different color than the message with Winston logger

I have this code for my Winston logger:

```
const winston = require('winston');
const moment = require('moment');
const { format, transports } = require('winston');
const { combine, json, timestamp, splat, printf, colorize } = format;

const customLevels = {
  levels: {
    error: 0,
    warn: 1,
    info: 2
  },
  colors: {
    info: 'blue bold',
    warn: 'yellow bold',
    error: 'red bold'
  },
  symbols: {
    info: '',
    warn: '⚠️ ',
    error: '❌'
  }
};

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  levels: customLevels.levels,
  format: combine(
    json(),
    timestamp(),
    splat(),
    printf(({ level, message, timestamp }) => {
      const formattedDate = moment.utc(timestamp).format('LL');
      const formattedTime = moment.utc(timestamp).format('HH:mm');
      const levelColorizer = colorize({ all: true });
      const messageColorizer = colorize({ colors: { msg: 'white bold' } });

      const symbol = customLevels.symbols[level] || '';

      const levelFormatted = levelColorizer.colorize(level, `${symbol} [${formattedDate} - ${formattedTime} - ${level.toUpperCase()}]:`);
      const messageFormatted = messageColorizer.colorize('msg', message);

      return `${levelFormatted} ${messageFormatted}`;
    })
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.Console()
  ]
});

winston.addColors(customLevels.colors);

module.exports = logger;
```

But when I log something what I get is this:

[image]

And I want that when a variable is printed along with a message, it is printed in a different color than the message.

How can I do it?